# Differences between primes which are powers of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, conjectures

Not for every prime $p$ there is smaller prime $q$ such that $p-q=2^n$ for some natural number $n$ and $n=127$ is an example. But what about the dual question:

> For each prime number $p>2$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $p+2^n$ is a prime number.

What is known about this?

Comment: You want $p>2$, I'm guessing.

Comment: Per [A076336](https://oeis.org/A076336) description it is conjectured to be also sequence of these counterexamples, smallest prime counterexample would then be $p=271129$.

Comment: @Sil  Interesting. Despite the similarities, I don't see why those two sequences should coincide.  Do you know if either inclusion can be demonstrated?

Comment: Worth remarking:  testing the conjectured least prime, $271129$, it seems (numerically) that each term in $\{271129+2^n\}$ is divisible by at least one of $\{3,5,7,13,17,241\}$ just as in my argument, so perhaps a proof along similar lines is possible.

Comment: @lulu Somewhere this seems to be called [dual Sierpinski problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_number#Dual_Sierpinski_problem) (although that wiki has no citation). Something about it can be found also [here](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=10754), and in turn [here](https://oeis.org/A076336/a076336c.html)

Comment: @Sil  Thanks!  I like problems connected to covering systems.  I can see why Sierpinski was attracted to conjectures like these.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon: …or allow $n=0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are infinitely many counterexamples.

Consider $n\pmod {24}$.   We consider a covering system for such residues.  Specifically, remark that:

$$n\equiv 1 \pmod 2\implies 2^n\equiv 2\pmod 3$$
$$n\equiv 2 \pmod 4\implies 2^n\equiv 4\pmod 5$$
$$n\equiv 1 \pmod 3\implies 2^n\equiv 2\pmod 7$$
$$n\equiv 4 \pmod 8\implies 2^n\equiv 16\pmod {17}$$
$$n\equiv 8 \pmod {12}\implies 2^n\equiv 9\pmod {13}$$
$$n\equiv 0 \pmod {24}\implies 2^n\equiv 1\pmod {241}$$

These are easily verified, case by case.  And it is easily verified that each $n\in \mathbb N$ satisfies at least one of the congruences.

Thus we are lead to consider: $$\text{ChineseRemainder[\{1,1,5,1,4,240\},\{3,5,7,17,13,241\}]}=1518781$$

Any prime congruent to that $\pmod {3\times 5\times 7\times 13\times 17\times 241}$ will be a counterexample, and by Dirichlet there are infinitely many of these.

The least such prime is $68627641$, followed by $202845361$.

Of course, there might be smaller counterexamples...but these counterexamples are guaranteed to allow small prime factors for every $n$.

Comment: Could this idea be used on $2^i\cdot 3^j$?

Comment: It would be harder.  My argument really uses the fact that I have a single natural number $n$ to deal with.